# GWT client side error (TypeError): b is null

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, requestfactory

I have simple GWT 2.4.0 RequestFactory application, which fails with client side exception when fire method calls.

```
context.checkPassword(tbLogin.getText(), ptbPasswd.getText())
        .fire(new Receiver<EmployeeProxy>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(EmployeeProxy response) {
                Window.alert(response == null ?
                        "Login faild!" :
                        response.getDisplayName()
                                + " login success!");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(ServerFailure error) {
                Window.alert("Somthing wrong");
            }

        });
```

FireBug and Chrome Developer Tools shows nothing. I just recive an alert message:

```
(TypeError): b is null
 fileName: http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html
 stack: Oz(null,"{\"F\":\"ru.itskills.daxx.acme.client.EmployeeRequestFactory\",\"I\":[{\"O\":\"yGR3sMWWOGTu_ikQGxTCqleAi3E=\",\"P\":[\"cas\",\"cas1\"]}]}",[object Object])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1197
gB([object Object],null)@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1169
jB([object Object])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1079
VA([object Object],[object Object])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:475
YW([object Object])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1172
Pc([object Object])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1253
Bc([object Object])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1253
Ad([object Object],[object Object],null)@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1216
sd([object Object],[object Object])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1170
Ho([object Object],[object Object])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:532
Hc([object MouseEvent],[object Object],[object HTMLButtonElement])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1077
Jo([object Object],[object MouseEvent])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1014
Ro([object MouseEvent])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1253
vn([object MouseEvent],[object HTMLButtonElement],[object Object])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:935
([object MouseEvent])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1250
zb((function (a) {var b, c = this;while (c && !(b = c.__listener)) {c = c.parentNode;}c && c.nodeType != 1 && (c = null);b && $n(b) && vn(a, c, b);}),[object HTMLButtonElement],[object Arguments])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:663
Cb((function (a) {var b, c = this;while (c && !(b = c.__listener)) {c = c.parentNode;}c && c.nodeType != 1 && (c = null);b && $n(b) && vn(a, c, b);}),[object HTMLButtonElement],[object Arguments])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:1164
([object MouseEvent])@http://localhost:8084/app/BDB5AC36BC159624D4B51B3846C167DF.cache.html:965

 lineNumber: 1197
```

What could it be and how to fix it?

Same error after 'Detailed' mode compilation.

```
(TypeError): this$static is null
 fileName: http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html
 stack: com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_gwt_client_DefaultRequestTransport_$send__Lcom_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_gwt_client_DefaultRequestTransport_2Ljava_lang_String_2Lcom_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_RequestTransport$TransportReceiver_2V(null,"{\"F\":\"ru.itskills.daxx.acme.client.EmployeeRequestFactory\",\"I\":[{\"O\":\"yGR3sMWWOGTu_ikQGxTCqleAi3E=\",\"P\":[\"cas\",\"cas1\"]}]}",[object Object])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:6394
com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_AbstractRequestContext_$doFire__Lcom_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_AbstractRequestContext_2Lcom_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_Receiver_2V([object Object],null)@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:6925
com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_AbstractRequestContext_$fire__Lcom_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_AbstractRequestContext_2V([object Object])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:6993
com_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_AbstractRequest_$fire__Lcom_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_impl_AbstractRequest_2Lcom_google_web_bindery_requestfactory_shared_Receiver_2V([object Object],[object Object])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:6825
ru_itskills_daxx_acme_client_App$1_$onClick__Lru_itskills_daxx_acme_client_App$1_2Lcom_google_gwt_event_dom_client_ClickEvent_2V([object Object])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:14243
com_google_gwt_event_dom_client_ClickEvent_dispatch__Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_EventHandler_2V([object Object])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:713
com_google_gwt_event_shared_GwtEvent_dispatch__Ljava_lang_Object_2V([object Object])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:633
com_google_web_bindery_event_shared_SimpleEventBus_$doFire__Lcom_google_web_bindery_event_shared_SimpleEventBus_2Lcom_google_web_bindery_event_shared_Event_2Ljava_lang_Object_2V([object Object],[object Object],null)@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:916
com_google_gwt_event_shared_HandlerManager_$fireEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_HandlerManager_2Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_GwtEvent_2V([object Object],[object Object])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:848
com_google_gwt_user_client_ui_Widget_$fireEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_Widget_2Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_GwtEvent_2V([object Object],[object Object])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:2898
com_google_gwt_event_dom_client_DomEvent_fireNativeEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_dom_client_NativeEvent_2Lcom_google_gwt_event_shared_HasHandlers_2Lcom_google_gwt_dom_client_Element_2V([object MouseEvent],[object Object],[object HTMLButtonElement])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:662
com_google_gwt_user_client_ui_Widget_$onBrowserEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_ui_Widget_2Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Event_2V([object Object],[object MouseEvent])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:2926
com_google_gwt_user_client_ui_Widget_onBrowserEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Event_2V([object MouseEvent])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:2993
com_google_gwt_user_client_DOM_dispatchEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Event_2Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Element_2Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_EventListener_2V([object MouseEvent],[object HTMLButtonElement],[object Object])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:2348
([object MouseEvent])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:2617
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_apply__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2((function (evt) {var listener, curElem = this;while (curElem && !(listener = curElem.__listener)) {curElem = curElem.parentNode;}curElem && curElem.nodeType != 1 && (curElem = null);listener && com_google_gwt_user_client_impl_DOMImpl_isMyListener__Ljava_lang_Object_2Z(listener) && com_google_gwt_user_client_DOM_dispatchEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Event_2Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Element_2Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_EventListener_2V(evt, curElem, listener);}),[object HTMLButtonElement],[object Arguments])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:269
com_google_gwt_core_client_impl_Impl_entry0__Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2Ljava_lang_Object_2((function (evt) {var listener, curElem = this;while (curElem && !(listener = curElem.__listener)) {curElem = curElem.parentNode;}curElem && curElem.nodeType != 1 && (curElem = null);listener && com_google_gwt_user_client_impl_DOMImpl_isMyListener__Ljava_lang_Object_2Z(listener) && com_google_gwt_user_client_DOM_dispatchEvent__Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Event_2Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_Element_2Lcom_google_gwt_user_client_EventListener_2V(evt, curElem, listener);}),[object HTMLButtonElement],[object Arguments])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:301
([object MouseEvent])@http://localhost:8888/app/247A5A4B14F8C1DBCC38D63FB852104D.cache.html:286

 lineNumber: 6394
```

Comment: There is a NullPointerException in the code. Does your code work properly in the Development mode? If it still works fine, you can compile your code with 'PRETTY' mode so that the compiled javascript is descriptive. So, you can figure out the variable which is null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet you forgot to `initialize()` your RequestFactory.

Comment: Oh, you're right. I created 2 factory instances, initialized one of them and use another one.

Answer (score 2):

From your code snippet, three things can be `null` and are not checked:

1. `tbLogin.getText()`
2. `ptbPasswd.getText()`
3. `response.getDisplayName()`

To track down the problem, compile the project with "Output style: Detailed" and re-test. The error will show the Java stack instead of the "b is null".

[image]

If you are compiling via ANT, add the `-style DETAILED` arg, e.g.:

```
<java failonerror="true" fork="true" classname="com.google.gwt.dev.Compiler">
    ...
    <arg line="-style" />
    <arg value="DETAILED" />
    ...
</java>
```